# Getting error while consuming kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am getting below error while I am consuming message from kafka broker, can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong or i am missing, I have put the steps i am following to create a topi , produce a message and then consume the message (FYI this is on HDP 2.5.5, and kafka 0.10.x)

export BK="node1:6667,node1:6667,node1:6667"

export ZK="zk1:2181,zk1:2181,zk1:2181"

Created a topic:
Kinit to kafka user
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zk1:2181,zk1:2181,zk1:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic test3

List the topics:
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper zk1:2181,zk1:2181,zk1:2181 localhost:2181
Produce a message on a topic:
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list $BK  --topic test3
I can produce message 
or with port 9092
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list node1:9092,node2:9092,node2:9092 --topic test3

Consume the message:
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper $ZK --bootstrap-server $BK  --topic test3 --from-beginning 
also tried with –security-protocol PLAINTEXTSASL getting error :
[2017-06-21 02:09:09,620] WARN Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Zookeeper client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. Make sure that the client is configured to use a ticket cache (using the JAAS configuration setting 'useTicketCache=true)' and restart the client. If you still get this message after that, the TGT in the ticket cache has expired and must be manually refreshed. To do so, first determine if you are using a password or a keytab. If the former, run kinit in a Unix shell in the environment of the user who is running this Zookeeper client using the command 'kinit ' (where  is the name of the client's Kerberos principal). If the latter, do 'kinit -k -t  ' (where  is the name of the Kerberos principal, and  is the location of the keytab file). After manually refreshing your cache, restart this client. If you continue to see this message after manually refreshing your cache, ensure that your KDC host's clock is in sync with this host's clock. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[2017-06-21 02:09:09,622] WARN SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No password provided Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) No brokers found in ZK.

Comment: Can you try the consumer without --zookeeper flag. If you are using the new consumer in 0.10.2 it's not needed. If you provide --zookeeper then it tries to use the old 0.8 consumer.

Comment: I did try without --zookeeper and I was asked to enter more parameters then I added zookeeper

Comment: Depending on the version you may also need to add --new-consumer to force it to use the new consumer. This is now the default but was not in older versions like 0.9.

Comment: It looks like you have created topic with only one parition. If that particular broker node will be down then consumer will not be able to consume. Try altering the topic with more partitions. Also as you are using 0.10.x you need to use ```kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server node1:9092,node2:9092,node2:9092 --topic test```

Comment: hans you are right, it was actually new consumer issue , I overcame it by manually providing permission on that particular topic to user and consumer group and issue was resolved.